# How to push on new screen after dismiss model sheet in SwiftUI?

Tags: model, navigation, swiftui, uimodalpresentationstyle, swiftui-navigationlink

**I Have to Implement like** To create a login screen in the screen user can enter mobile number  and click on the login button  model sheet will open for top verification  after OTP verification sheet  must be dismiss and navigate on the dashboard.

Here i created a content View on that contentView click on the **Open model** button, model sheet **(sheetView)** will open after the click on **done** button sheet will dismiss than screen navigate from **ContentView** to **DashboardView**.

**// ContentView**

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var isAction: Bool = false
    @State var isDashboard: Bool = false

    var body: some View {

        NavigationView{

            Button(action: {
                self.isAction.toggle()
            }) {
                Text("Open Model")
            }.sheet(isPresented: $isAction) {

                sheetView(isDissmis: self.$isAction) { (isNavigateOnDashboard) in

                    print(isNavigateOnDashboard ?? false)

                    return self.isDashboard = isNavigateOnDashboard ?? false
                }
            }
            NavigationLink(destination: DashboardView(), isActive: self.$isDashboard) {
                EmptyView()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**//sheetView:-**  it presents as `modalPresentationStyle` in the form of sheet present.

```
struct sheetView: View {

    @Binding var isDissmis: Bool
    var isNavigateDashboard: ((Bool?)) -> Void?
    var body: some View {

        NavigationView{
            Text("Here i have to verifiy Some details")
                .navigationBarItems(trailing: doneButton)
        }
    }

    var doneButton: some  View {

        Button(action: {
            self.isDissmis = false
            self.isNavigateDashboard(true)
        }) {
            Text("Done").bold()
        }
    }
}
```

**//Dashboard:-** after dismiss model(sheet) screen should be navigate on the Dashboard.

```
struct DashboardView: View {

    var body: some View {

        TabView{

            Text("Home").tabItem{
                Image(systemName: "1.circle")
                Text("Home")
            }

            Text("Activity").tabItem{
                Image(systemName: "2.circle")
                Text("Activity")
            }
            Text("profile").tabItem{
                Image(systemName: "3.circle")
                Text("profile")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any clue for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your `ContentView` `body` in this way, and when you dismiss the sheet view, it will navigate to `DashboardView`

also, there is no need to use clouser callback in your `SheetView`

```swift
var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            VStack {
                Button(action: {
                    self.isAction.toggle()
                }) {
                    Text("Open Model")
                }.sheet(isPresented: $isAction, onDismiss: {
                    self.isDashboard.toggle()
                }) {
                    sheetView(isDissmis: self.$isAction)
                }
                NavigationLink(destination: DashboardView(), isActive: $isDashboard) {
                    EmptyView()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```